# PHP function parameters from a string

Tags: php, function, parameters, eval

How do I make a truely dynamic function with dynamic parameters call? The documentation and examples I've found all assume you have only 1 parameter. I would like to have multiple parameters, example:

```
class Object {
    function A($p1) {}
    function B($p1,$p2) {}
}

$obj = new Object();
$function = "B";
$params = "'foo', 'me'";

$obj->$function($params);
```

calling `$function = "A"` will be fine as $params is treated as a string. I've tried

```
$obj->$function(explode(',',$params));
```

for `$function="B"` but it does not work as explode simply returns 
an array and thus function B has a missing parameter.

Any idea?

Comment: For my usage, I'm writing a model loader. It enables us to load any model and execute it without specifying specific model in the code. Similar to Java's dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
call_user_func_array(array($obj, "B"), str_getcsv($params));
```

Comment: @cfoo Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. For more information, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function as follows:

```
call_user_func_array(array($obj, $function), explode(',', $params));
```